# What does -line flag do in tcl regular expression?

Tags: regex, tcl

Below I have copied the code I had written. I don't know what the line flag does.

```
set value "hi this is venkat345
hi this is venkat435
hi this is venkat567"

regexp -all -line -- {(venkat.+)$} $value a b  
puts "Full Match: $a"
puts "Sub Match1: $b"
```

The above code gives the following output

```
Full Match: venkat567
Sub Match1: venkat567
```

Can any one explain me when and where should I choose the -line flag in tcl regular expression

Comment: try `regexp -all -line -- {.*(venkat.+)$} $value a b `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [man page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm#M8) has defined it well I believe:

> **-line**
>
> Enables newline-sensitive matching. By default, newline is a completely ordinary character with no special meaning. With this flag, `[^` bracket expressions and `.` never match newline, `^` matches an empty string after any newline in addition to its normal function, and `$` matches an empty string before any newline in addition to its normal function. This flag is equivalent to specifying both `-linestop` and `-lineanchor`, or the `(?n)` embedded option (see the [**re_syntax**](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm) manual page).

If you want to understand it another way, `.` and `[^ ... ]` usually match newlines, for example:

```
regexp -- {^....$} "ab\nc"
```

returns `1` (meaning the regexp matches the string, counting `\n` as 1 character) but using the `-line` switch will prevent `.` to match `\n`.

Similary:

```
regexp -- {^[^abc]+$} "de\nf"
```

will also return 1 because the negated class `[^abc]` is able to match a character that is not `abc`, which includes `\n`.

The second function of the `-line` switch makes `^` match at every beginning of line instead of matching only at the start of the whole string, and makes `$` match at every end of line instead of matching only at the end of the whole string.

```
% set text {abc
abc}
abc
abc
% regexp -- {^abc$} $text
0
% regexp -line -- {^abc$} $text
1
```

As for the when and where, it will depend on what you are trying to do. Based on your sample code, it would seem to me that you need to get all the usernames beginning with `venkat` that can appear at the end of any line. Since you want to match many, you will need to use the `-all` and `-inline` switches to get the matched strings, and I would recommend to change the regexp a bit:

```
set value "hi this is venkat345
hi this is venkat435
hi this is venkat567"

# I removed the capture group and changed . to \S to match non-space characters
set results [regexp -all -inline -line -- {venkat\S+$} $value]
puts $results
# venkat345 venkat435 venkat567
```

Answer (score 1):

`-line` just make sure your `.` will never match a newline.

According to the [Tcl regexp documentation](http://wiki.tcl.tk/986):

> -line
>
> Enables newline-sensitive matching. By default, newline is a
>   completely ordinary character with no special meaning. With this flag,
>   ‘[^’ bracket expressions and ‘.’ never match newline, ‘^’ matches an
>   empty string after any newline in addition to its normal function, and
>   ‘$’ matches an empty string before any newline in addition to its
>   normal function. This flag is equivalent to specifying both -linestop
>   and -lineanchor, or the (?n) embedded option (see METASYNTAX, below).

Here is the output without `-line` option:

```
Full Match: venkat345                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
hi this is venkat435                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
hi this is venkat567                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Sub Match1: venkat345                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
hi this is venkat435                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
hi this is venkat567
```

The `.+` just matches all the lines up to the `value` string end.